# how to get information from a link in php

Tags: php

If give you a link like `http://login.php?workerid=abc`,
how can we get the information of workerid in php? Thanks.
Maybe `$_GET` function, but do not know exactly how to make that work.

Comment: This is so basic you clearly did *no* research on your own

Comment: This is so basic you clearly did *no* research on your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get information from url like this

```
$data=$_GET['workerid'];
```